# csv.DictReader giving unexpected results

Tags: python, csv, keyerror

My CSV file:

```
website, username, password
google.com, test1, lamepass
instagram.com, test2, passlame
```

My python script:

```
with open(database_path) as database:
    csv_read = csv.DictReader(database)
    for card in csv_read:
        print(card['website'])
```

Which returns:

```
google.com
instagram.com
```

But this code:

```
with open(database_path) as database:
    csv_read = csv.DictReader(database)
    for card in csv_read:
        print(card['password'])
```

Returns:

```
KeyError: 'password'
```

I don't understand the issue, and online resources just show examples, none of them explain this problem. They do talk about `KeyError`s, but they don't seem to address how the CSV file contains the key (`'password'`), but still returns key error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You could also add a keyword argument `skipinitialspace=True` to your `csv.DictReader(database)` call instead of physically removing the space characters between delimiters in the file. See [`Dialect.skipinitialspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) in documentation. Also, if you had added a `print(card)` to the `for` loop, you would have seen right away that there was no key in the dictionary displayed equal to `'password'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your csv file, there are spaces between the comma separated values. Remove them and it should work.

Othewise try this:

```
import csv

with open(database_path) as database:
    csv_read = csv.DictReader(database)

    for card in csv_read:
        print(card[" password"]) # notice the space!!!
```

Comment: @Beejo Here's a trick to keep in mind for these kinds of situations: Reverse the process. E.g. use a DictWriter, output some sample records, look at the result, spot the differences.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra space before `password` (and `username`):

```
csv = """website, username, password
google.com, test1, lamepass
instagram.com, test2, passlame"""

with open('file.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(csv)

import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r+') as database:
    csv_read = csv.DictReader(database)
    for card in csv_read:
        print(card)


OrderedDict([('website', 'google.com'), (' username', ' test1'), (' password', ' lamepass')])
OrderedDict([('website', 'instagram.com'), (' username', ' test2'), (' password', ' passlame')])
```

You should try to remove the extra spaces from your csv with this:

```
csv = csv.replace(", ", ",")
```

Comment: @Beejo sure, also I usually use pandas for manipulating csv files. maybe dictwriter is better for simple tasks